Pixi.js - How to use masking without enabled WebGL
I was using the mask property of the Graphics object and it worked fine, because the browsers had WebGL enabled. How can I do it to use masking even there is no WebGL enabled. s. Here is the part of the code, where I use the mask, when WebGL is enabled:

      const maskObj = new Graphics();

      maskObj.beginFill(0xffffff);
      maskObj.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
      this.mask = maskObj;
      this.addChild(maskObj);

this.mask is the property from the Class Container
I heard that it could work with canvasRenderer but I have not seen many examples with that class
